# Unicode composed and decomposed forms

Tags: unicode

I know there are composed and decomposed variants of certain characters. I also understand application should be consistent and use one or another and face challenges when working with 3rd parties.

What I don't quite understand is:
- why those 2 forms exist
- which one should I choose when implementing a simple backend database?

It seems majority is using composed form (Windows, SMB). MacOSX on HFS+ is using decomposed form on the other hand.

For example when used composed and decomposed accented French e (é) they look the same on the screen but searching may not return result and sorting may not work as expected. I'm leaning towards composed form but then seems to me French and Frénch (I know it's not a good example) will not be 'close to each other' in result set and probably they should.

I'm not sure what Lucene is doing...
What are recommendations for my use case?

Updated 2015-02-19

The problem is which form NFC or NFD should be used to persist strings, filenames etc in the backend database?
Also I'm implementing VFS for Windows, Linux, MacOSX so returning consistent view of the filesystem is essential.
By the look of it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1173/_index.html
Mac likes to receive filenames in decomposed form so normalisation has to be done for that platform.

Comment: As a general question, this is way too broad, and also largely opinion-based. As regards to your use case, you have not actually described it. Even with a detailed description of the intended processing of data and tools used in it, I'm afraid this would be off-topic at SO.

Comment: The obvious Google hits cover a lot of this ground.  http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/ and http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html and maybe also read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence too.  TR#15 contains the word "recommend" twice, both times with NFC, but if you care about e <-> é near-equivalence, decomposed may be a better choice.

Comment: Good links from Unicode.org. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Composed and decomposed forms exist for compatibility: there are multiple encodings that have composed characters and Unicode has to allow round-trip lossless conversion with all of them. The most egregious example I know of is Windows-1258, which allows for the same accented character to be represented in composed and decomposed form, just like Unicode.

   The reason they are not adding new precomposed characters is simply that there are no new encodings that would require it.
2. The main reasons to prefer composed characters are better rendering support in older software and apparent simplicity for most use cases. Whether those are important, you have to decide for yourself.
3. Lucene has several filters that deal with this issue, for example `ICUFoldingFilter`.
4. As for sorting, the naive algorithm fails regardless if you use composed or decomposed characters. I recommend using a decent Unicode collation library for your language of choice.